# sql query that removes subdirectories in string

Tags: mysql

I would like to do an Update query that changes the path of images for several entries with different date style directories. 
Basically each individual image is in a folder named with a specific date stamp

So they are all the same length of character.

So it would update lines in the database from this

```
/wp-content/uploads/20180711125044/sample.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/20180812125044/sample_2.jpg
```

to this:

```
/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/sample_2.jpg
```

(removing the folders in between 'uploads' and the 'jpg' name)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you're using 8.0 you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: Is the `/wp-content/uploads/` prefix always the same?

Comment: If it's the same prefix, and the number is always the same length, you can use `SUBSTR()` to get the parts before and after the number, and then concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SET @val ='/wp-content/uploads/20180711125044/sample.jpg';
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, '/uploads/', 1),
    '/uploads/',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@val, '/', -1)
  ) AS result;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3rbanfeFvH8cjkGaGCKTjS/1).